# Drag and drop html from buider

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drag-and-drop, editor

i need a drag and drop form builder(free/paid) something similar to [react email editor](https://github.com/unlayer/react-email-editor)

[image]
in which i can add custom component too and edit there property (like name,ids,and,select value(in case of select tag)) and resize the componant. if there is any please suggest one

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery plugin called Form builder

I have used this [Form Builder](https://formbuilder.online) Plugin and I found it to very useful, this is free plugin and you can customize this plugin as per your need and also add new controls as per your requirements.

To add this write the code as below

```html
<body>
  <div id="fb-editor"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://formbuilder.online/assets/js/form-builder.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $(document.getElementById('fb-editor')).formBuilder();
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: i have already try that but in this you can not add two input side by side also cant add custom fields

Comment: You can do any type of customization using this plugin it was life savior for me

Comment: tell me how to customize for function show in image https://ibb.co/mJ0cP4K

Comment: Please go through the [documents](https://formbuilder.online/docs/) given in this link. For side by side control you can do that in css also no need to edit in js file

Comment: i can't find any option in docs if you can do this can you share you code?